# Vim, how to avoid :set cuc side effect of setting column number

Tags: vim

Possibly this is a bug, but I'm not sure.  Through user fow in #vim on freenode, I've confirmed no side effect in 7.3.409, but there is a side effect in 7.3.547 (the version on my computer.)

The easiest way to test is to copy paste the following file into a vim buffer, jump to the beginning (gg) and follow the instructions.

```
Hi there, this is a test case.
This line is short.

After opening this file issue the following commands:
$j:set cuc<Enter>k

You'll notice that the cursor should be on the period after "case" this is expected behavior.

Next enter the following commands:
:set nocuc<Enter>$hj:set cuc<Enter>k

You'll notice that the cursor should now be on the word "a" rather than on the "e" at the end of "case"

So when you have a column value (not end of line) then :set cuc modifies this value as a sideeffect.
```

Is there anyway to workaround this issue?  Is this a bug?  Can anyone else reproduce?

Comment: I confirm your observation in 7.3.854. You should try [the vim-dev mailing list](http://www.vim.org/maillist.php#vim-dev). And I don't think this question is suitable for SO.